# Possible to consolidate DB hits when using callbacks in controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I find myself trying to segment code as much as possible into callbacks for controller logic.  But I'm starting to worry about performance.  In the below example I have to query for the same Vote instance 3x when hitting vote#update.  Is there anyway to pass an object around so that I can maintain my callbacks but only query the db once?  Am I missing some mechanism in Rails?

```
class VoteController < ApplicationController
    #Access limitations etc.
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :correct_user_vote, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :election_concluded_check, only: [:update]

    def edit
        @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])

        if !@vote.nil? && @vote.update_attributes(vote_params)
            redirect_to party_path(@vote.party_id)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    private

        def correct_user_vote
            vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
            if vote.nil? || current_user.id!=vote.user_id
                flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
                redirect_to root_path
            end
        end

        def election_concluded_check
            # Do not allow updating of votes if party.concluded
            vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
            if vote.nil? || vote.election.concluded
                flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
                redirect_to root_path
            end
        end

        def vote_params
            params[:vote].permit(:candidate_id,:note)
        end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your vote into an instance variable in a `before_action`, then use it in all subsequent `before_action`s:

```
class VoteController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_vote, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user_vote, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :election_concluded_check, only: [:update]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @vote.update_attributes(vote_params)
      redirect_to party_path(@vote.party_id)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private

  def find_vote
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user_vote
    if current_user.id != @vote.user_id
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def election_concluded_check
    # Do not allow updating of votes if party.concluded
    if @vote.election.concluded
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

The reason you can do this is that instance variables (variables that begin with `@`) are accessible between methods in the same object. So you can set the `@vote` in one method (`find_vote`), then access it in other methods of the same object (`update`, for example). In this case, the `@vote` is only loaded the one time in the `find_vote` method.

Also notice that once you load the `@vote` instance variable in a `before_action`, you no longer need to do anything in your `edit` method, which is a nice side effect of this approach.

As a side note, assuming that `Vote` is an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass, when you do `@vote = Vote.find(id)`, the `@vote` object will never be `nil`, since `ActiveRecord::Base#find` throws an exception if it doesn't find the record you're asking for. So there's really no need to check for `@vote.nil?` ever.

Answer (score -1):

The usual technique is to replace your variables with a method that caches the object on first access. For example:

```
  def edit
    @vote = vote
  end

private

  def vote
    @_vote ||= Vote.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user_vote
    if vote.nil? || current_user.id != vote.user_id
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately Rails thinks that it is a good idea to pass information to your views using instance variables so you need to be careful about how you name your cached value (hence the `@_vote` instead of `@vote`).